# Vim insert mode not allowing editing of existing lines in file, only newly added lines

Tags: vim

It used to be that when I went into insert mode on an existing file, I could hit "delete" and that would work. Now I can still delete and modify things that I newly add to a file, but if there is existing stuff there once I open a file, I do not have the ability to delete that. I can only delete and modify new stuff. Out of insert mode however I still have the ability to delete things with the regular `dd` type commands. My .vimrc is pretty simple, and my only addon is SuperTab.

Here is my .vimrc if that helps:

```
set tags=./tags,~/kent/src/tags,~/kent/src/lib/tags,~/kent/src/inc/tags,~/kent/src/hg/lib/tags,~/kent/src/hg/inc/tags,~/kent/src/jkOwnLib/tags  
syntax on
filetype indent plugin on
set modeline
au FileType python setlocal tabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
set background=dark
set wildmode=longest,list,full
set wildmenu
```

And here is the output from `vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb  8 2012 10:41:54)
Included patches: 1-434
Compiled by John St. John
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm -mouse_urxvt +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
-sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/cluster/home/jstjohn/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc44 -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/usr/include  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1  
Linking: gcc44   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim       -lm -lncurses -lnsl  -lselinux      -L/hive/groups/recon/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic  -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.4 -ldl -lpthread -lieee -lm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to `set backspace+=start`.  Generally you probably want `set backspace=indent,eol,start`, but just "start" should solve this problem specifically.

See `:help 'backspace'` for more information on the other options.